# fatal error (JVM Crashed) while passing array of properties from c to java using jni

Tags: java, c, jvm, java-native-interface

i want to read file and pass file contents from c to java using properties collection.
I got
" A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:"
what would be the problem

**C code**

```
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_jniex2_view
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject this){
    fr=fopen("lmf.txt","r");  
    jclass cls_Properties = (*env)->FindClass(env,"java/util/Properties");
    jmethodID mid_Properties_ctor = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,cls_Properties, "<init>", "()V");
    jmethodID mid_Properties_put = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,cls_Properties, "put", "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
    jstring title = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"title");
    jstring author = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"searchtag");
    jstring year = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"year");
    jstring genre = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"genre");
    jstring rating = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"rating");
    jstring searchtag =(*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"searchtag");
    int i=0,m=0;
    while(fscanf(fr,"%[^:]:%s %s %s %s %s\n",s1,t1,a1,y2,g1,r1)!=EOF){
        m++;
    }
    jobjectArray ret = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env,m, cls_Properties, 0);
    while(fscanf(fr,"%[^:]:%s %s %s %s %s\n",s1,t1,a1,y2,g1,r1)!=EOF){
        printf("%[^:]:%s %s %s %s %s\n",s1,t1,a1,y2,g1,r1);
        jobject prop = (*env)->NewObject(env,cls_Properties, mid_Properties_ctor);
        (*env)->PushLocalFrame(env,6);
        (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env,prop, mid_Properties_put, title, (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,t1));
        (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env,prop, mid_Properties_put, author, (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,a1));
        (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env,prop, mid_Properties_put, year, (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"2000"));
        (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env,prop, mid_Properties_put, genre, (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,g1));
        (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env,prop, mid_Properties_put, rating, (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"4.5"));
        (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env,prop, mid_Properties_put, searchtag, (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,s1));
        prop = (*env)->PopLocalFrame(env,prop);
        (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,ret, i, prop);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fr);
    return ret;    
}
```

The java code that invokes view() funtion.

***Java Code***

```
public class jniex2{
    public native  Properties[] view();
    static{
        System.loadLibrary("hello1");
    }
    public static void main(String ar[])throws IOException,FileNotFoundException{  
        Properties[] records = jn.view();      
        for(Properties record:records){
            System.out.println("title:"+record.getProperty("title"));
            System.out.println("author:"+record.getProperty("author"));
            System.out.println("year:"+record.getProperty("year"));
            System.out.println("genre:"+record.getProperty("genre"));
            System.out.println("rating:"+record.getProperty("rating"));
            System.out.println("searchtag:"+record.getProperty("searchtag"));
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea about Java interaction but your calls to `fscanf` don't contain any length limiter. That means you might scan more characters than fit into the destination buffers which could cause your crash. Also I would suggest to check the return value of `fscanf` to match the expected number of parameters,  not just `!= EOF`.

Comment: You could try running with `-Xcheck:jni` to see if that finds something.

Comment: Do you expect us to debug the code for you? First, find which line exactly results in a crash. Keep in mind that any JNI call can potentially throw an exception (which you don't check anywhere).

Comment: The complete lack of any error checking is almost certainly contributing to your inability to determine why you're getting crashes.  JNI calls can fail, and if you continue, you will usually see crashes.  JNI calls can also throw Java exceptions, and if you continue to make JNI calls with a pending Java exception, you will usually see crashes.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: In addition to other comments, you never rewind your filehandle, so the first loop (with `m++` in the body) eats the entire file and the second loop never executes.